# Boot Loop // No Bios // No Signal to Monitor // RAM Installment

Tags: boot, bios

I have an intel DH67CL Motherboard, AMD Radeon HD 6950 graphics card and 2x2gb DDR3 1333 mHz ram. I decided to buy new ram to upgrade my system so I bought Corsair 2x8gb DDR3 1600 mHz ram. It came in today, so I unplugged all my cables, cut the power off and opened my case. I thought I should clean it too, since it looked ultra-dusty, so I spent an hour or two disattachting the ram sticks, video card etc. and cleaning around with brushes. After I was done I installed the graphics card, old 2x2gigs of ram and the new 2x8 gigs of ram. I booted up and everything was fine, I went into the BIOS settings, I saw the "2+2+8+8", "20 gb memory" texts, so all of the rams were working.I browsed around to change the 1333 mHz value to 1600 value to match up the new ram and check if the other values were right (9-9-9-24 channel thing, I dont know it's name in English). I couldn't find it in any of the tabs, except, in the "Performance" tab, there was a text saying something like "Are you sure you want to edit this manually etc." something like that. I thought the setting I was looking for might be in there so I hit yes. The settings were there, it was already set to 9-9-9-24, the mHz value was 1333 but there were no "1600" option. Max was 1333. So I just left it like that, didn't change anything in any tab, (if I didn't do it accidentaly) and quit the bios settings with "saving the changes". (I know, I wish I hadn't pressed that.)

And since then, I cannot boot my pc. When I try to boot it, the lights turn on, all of the fans start turning (like revving) and after 1-2 seconds everything turns off. Then it all starts running again, then turns off again. Meanwhile there is no signal on the monitor, it never gets out sleep mode. I can turn it off by holding the front power key, when I do that, I hear a "beep" then the system shuts down for good.

Things I've tried so far:
Detaching all ram sticks, trying them all one by one / in pairs.
Detaching and re-attaching the graphics card,
Making sure all the plugs and ports firmly sits in place,
BIOS reset through Jumper Modification (It gets out of boot loop, but still no signal on the monitor, so no bios. when i return to the default jumper mode, boot loop starts again)
BIOS reset through battery removal // waited 30 mins, nothing changes.
The "paperclip" method to make sure the power source was working, and it was. I managed to run it without attaching it to the motherboard.

I'm hoping that I haven't damaged any hardware when I was cleaning, but I paid extra attention when cleaning the fans not to spin them, I touched other pieces of metal before handling the hardware to rid out of static, absolutely never used a vacuum.

I'm sorry for the cringey English and the long story, but I tried to caption everything so that it may help accelerate the solution process. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your motherboard does not support the RAM you got. It doesn't support that speed of RAM.

Below are the memory specs from the [documentation](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/19486/eng/DH67CF_ProductGuide01_English.pdf) of your motherboard

> Memory
>   • Two 240-pin DDR3 SDRAM Dual Inline Memory Module (DIMM)
>   sockets
>   • Dual Channel DDR3 1333 MHz and DDR3 1066 MHz support
>   • Support for 1 Gb, 2 Gb, and 4 Gb memory technology
>   • Support for up to 16 GB of system memory with two DIMMs using 4 Gb memory technology
>   • Support for non-ECC memory
>   • Support for 1.35 V low voltage JEDEC memory

Comment: Two independent memory channels with interleaved mode support
Support for non-ECC, unbuffered, single-sided or double-sided DIMMs with x8 organization and single-sided DIMMs with x16 organization
32 GB maximum total system memory (with 4 Gb memory technology)

DDR3 1333 MHz and DDR3 1066 MHz SDRAM DIMMs

It says here that it supports up to 32 gb ram, and I know that it doesn't support 1600 but I expected it the 1600 rams to work in 1333 speed.
But that's not the problem now, I can always return the rams, I cannot break the boot loop even with the old rams.